# SVN - Redirect the request from one repos to another repos

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, svn, visualsvn-server

I need to redirect the request of one file which is present in one repository to the file present in another repository.

How to do this in svn by using Apache rewrite module ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your question is not clear, so you may want to reword it and provide more information on your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use mod_rewrite for this. Use [`svn:externals` (externals definitions)](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/externals/).